# Autoindent second line of plain text bullet list item

Tags: indentation, formatting

When using plain text I write bullet lists like this (second and further lines indented with two spaces):

```
* blah blah blah
  blah blah

* yadda yadda yadda
```

Problem is, when I start out a new bullet item:

```
* blah blah blah
```

and then press `Enter`, the second line isn't automatically indented like I want it to be:

```
* blah blah blah
blah
```

Since I have `autoindent` set, once I correct the indentation of the second line the third and subsequent lines indent correctly.  Also, if I use `gq` to format the bullet list item it will format it the way I want.  But I want vim to automatically handle it.

Also, I want the indentation mechanism to indent two spaces further if I hit `Enter` when the first non-whitespace character on the line is a `*`, to deal with nested bullet items.  For instance, if I have:

```
* blah blah
  * yadda yadda
```

When I hit `Enter` at the end of the "yadda"s I want the indentation to be at 4 spaces instead of 2, so when I type more "yadda"s it comes out like this:

```
* blah blah
  * yadda yadda
    yadda yadda
```

`formatexpr` is unset and `formatoptions` is `tcq`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it to do so by adding `r` to your `'formatoptions'` and amending your `'comments'` setting with the following commands:

```
set formatoptions+=r
set comments-=mb:*
set comments+=fb:*
```

(If you don't need to keep the rest of your `'comments'` setting, you could of course just use the single command: `set comments=fb:*`)

Note that this alters the `*` entry in your `comments` to match the existing `-` entry, which already indents in the manner you describe.

Some excerpts from `:help comments` explain how this works:

> Vim can automatically insert and format comments in a special way.  Vim
>   recognizes a comment by a specific string at the start of the line (ignoring white space).  Three types of comments can be used:
>
> - A comment string that repeats at the start of each line.  An example is the type of comment used in shell scripts, starting with "#".
> - **A comment string that occurs only in the first line, not in the following lines.  An example is this list with dashes.**
>
> [...]
>
> The 'comments' option is a comma-separated list of parts.  Each part defines a type of comment string.  A part consists of:
>     {flags}:{string}
>
> {flags}:
>
> [...]
>
> b Blank (,  or ) required after {string}.
>
> f Only the first line has the comment string.  Do not repeat comment on the next line, but preserve indentation **(e.g., a bullet-list)**.

(emphasis mine)